# SCSS loop a function inside map

Tags: css, sass

Apologies if this is a stupid question — but is it possible to output a bunch of functions from a loop inside a map in SCSS?

The following code does **not** work, but it's sort of what I want to do.

```
$colorvars : (    
  red : #cc0000,
  blue : #1e8cea,
  green : #27a249,
  teal : #41bdbb,
  purple : #5c369e,
  yellow : #ecd340
)

$colors: (
  @each $key, $value in $colorsvars {
    $key : color-palette($value)
  }
)
```

the `color-palette($value)` is a function.

Check https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/LLvPPK?editors=1100 for more context if needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve there exactly but if you are trying to assign colour value  you could make this simpler then it is now.

```
$myColours: (
 first: #000000,
 second: #FF4400;
);
p { color: map-get($myColours, first); }
```

Check this link for more examples -> https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/using-sass-functions-to-access-complex-variable-maps

Comment: Hi Tomislav, I know how I can get the colors from a map array. But I want to use the $keys and $values from a map and assign them to a function thats called `color-palette()`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, and what would be expected output? Would it be `red : #cc0000` or would it be `red` or would it be `#cc0000` because I don't fully understand what are you trying to achieve with this function rather then getting the value from array that's assigned to the key.

Comment: The final output would be something like 
`red: color-palette(#cc0000), blue: color-palette(#1e8cea)` etc. But inside the $colors map

Comment: Still not quiet sure what would be the purpose of getting that sort of output to be honest. How would you use that inside your attributes? And after you compile that scss file what would you expect to get as a result from red: color-palette(#cc0000) ?